# Remove all dots and dashes from a text file. Without deleting periods

Tags: unix, sed

I have a text file that has Morse code in it. I must delete all the Morse code, but not the periods at the end of each sentence or the hyphen in "Edgar-Johns". The text file reads as follows:

```
A test to see if the morse code can be removed from a file. .--- -. ..
This is a test --. -.- .-- .. -.. --- .- .. of sorts and so on. Let's see if the
code snippets can be found.
Also can they be .- . -.- removed and yet leave the periods at the end of sentences alone. ---- -. There are also hyphenated words like the
following: Edgar-Johns. -.
```

I can take all of the dots and dashes out using `sed 's/[.-]//g'`, but that also takes away the periods and the hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Just require a space before a matching dot (or dash), match all the dots, dashes, and spaces in a row at once, and replace with a space instead of nothing:

```
sed 's/ [ .-]*/ /g'
```

Run on your sample text, the above command yields this output:

> A test to see if the morse code can be removed from a file.  This is a
>   test of sorts and so on. Let's see if the code snippets can be found.
>   Also can they be removed and yet leave the periods at the end of
>   sentences alone. There are also hyphenated words like the following:
>   Edgar-Johns.

Comment: and do it with -i flag to read and write to the same file   ----- -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]  edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not the most familiar with regular expressions so I can't tell you exactly how to type this, but the morse code is entirely made up of dots and dash "words" that are space separated, correct? If that's the case, you could use the pattern "space (any number of dots and dashes without letters) space" to remove just the morse code bits.